# Specifying a non-dll to be copied to all referencing projects' bin folders in a NuGet package

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I have two solutions, Foo and Bar.

One of the projects in Foo, Foo.A, outputs a nuget package, which our build server pushes to an internal nuget feed. One of the projects in Bar, Bar.A, references this nuget package.

Foo.A contains a config file, which I want to have copied to the bin output folder of Bar.A upon build. To accomplish this, I've come up with the following `nuspec`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Foo.A</id>
    <!-- rest of metadata omitted -->
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="Config/*.config" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="bin\$Configuration$\*.dll" target="lib" />
    <file src="bin\$Configuration$\*.pdb" target="lib" />
    <file src="Config\*.config" target="lib\Config" />
  </files>
</package>
```

This creates a package with an internal structure like this:

```
Foo.A.nupkg
|-- lib
|    |-- Config
|    |    +-- Foo.A.config
|    |-- Foo.A.dll
|    +-- Foo.A.pdb
+-- Foo.A.nuspec
```

where the metadata section in the nuspec above is preserved in `Foo.A.nuspec`, but the files section is gone.

When I import this package in `Bar.A` and build, I get the dll and pdb file from `Foo.A` copied to the bin folder, but not the `Config` directory.

I've read the relevant sections of the [nuspec reference](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference) a couple of times, but I'm not getting any wiser.

What do I need to do to get this working?